# Splitting of comma separated values

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, ssms

I have some columns with comma-separated values. For example

**A**

```
as,ad,af,ag
```

My manager wants the output looks like this:

---

### **A**

```
as                          

ad          

af          

ag
```

---

All these should come under one row. I guess we need to use something line break.

Hi can we use replace with char(13)+char(10) something. This one also works...

Thanks,
Shashra

Comment: duplucate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/314824/t-sql-opposite-to-string-concatenation-how-to-split-string-into-multiple-reco

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create a user defined UDF like the one shown below.  Then, just pass in the comma separated list from another query and it will return a table with each value in a separate row.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fnSplitStringAsTable] 
(
    @inputString varchar(MAX),
    @delimiter char(1) = ','
)
RETURNS 
@Result TABLE 
(
    Value varchar(MAX)
)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @chIndex int
    DECLARE @item varchar(100)

    -- While there are more delimiters...
    WHILE CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @inputString, 0) <> 0
        BEGIN
            -- Get the index of the first delimiter.
            SET @chIndex = CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @inputString, 0)

            -- Get all of the characters prior to the delimiter and insert the string into the table.
            SELECT @item = SUBSTRING(@inputString, 1, @chIndex - 1)

            IF LEN(@item) > 0
                BEGIN
                    INSERT INTO @Result(Value)
                    VALUES (@item)
                END

            -- Get the remainder of the string.
            SELECT @inputString = SUBSTRING(@inputString, @chIndex + 1, LEN(@inputString))
        END

    -- If there are still characters remaining in the string, insert them into the table.
    IF LEN(@inputString) > 0
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO @Result(Value)
            VALUES (@inputString)
        END

    RETURN 
END
```

Answer (score 6):

Check this without using User Defined Function

```
DECLARE @param VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @param = 'as,ad,af,ag'

SELECT Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS ColName  
FROM  
(
     SELECT CONVERT(XML, '<M>' + REPLACE(ColName, ',', '</M><M>') + '</M>') AS ColName  
     FROM  (SELECT @param AS ColName) TableName
 ) AS A CROSS APPLY ColName.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a)
```

Comment: This is the solution I needed because I do not have permission to modify the database schema.

Answer (score -2):

You want to use a string splitting function, like the one found [here](http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1665) for example.

Once you've created this function, you can:

```
select string as A
    from YourTable
        cross apply dbo.fnParseStringTSQL(A,',')
```

Comment: I TRIED LIKE THIS BUT I ITS NOT WORKING. IT SHOWING ALL THOSE 3 COMMA SEPERATED VALUES 3 TIMES(MEANS SHOWING 3 DUPLICATED ROWS WITH SAME VALUES)...

Comment: @Shahsra: Can you provide more details on the data you're testing with?